# How add popup notify after adding products to cart, Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

How to add a pop-up notification after adding products to the basket, there should be two buttons in the popup, (Yes and No)
If the user clicks "yes", then we add the product. If "no", then stay on this page and close the popup.

Comment: Requirement is not clear as you have posted that popup will come after product adding to cart and in the popup you want yes/no button if yes then only add product to cart and if no then stay on the page? So do you want confirmation after adding product to cart or you want to confirm from customer that if they want to add product to cart or not?

Comment: Customer Confirmation

Comment: Simply, there are goods that have available delivery today, so if the customer has one product that is available for delivery today, and when he tries to add a second product that does not have the ability to deliver the product today, we need to show a popup with in certain text, if he clicks yes, we will add the product to the cart.